# How to add validation rule with where condition in laravel 8?

Tags: laravel-8

```
    $validatedData = $this->validate($request, [
        'ldate' => 'required',
        'type' => 'required',
        'daytype' => 'required',
        'employee' => 'required', 'exists:leaves,bemployee'  //where condition i need here
        'bemployee' => 'required',
        'subject' => 'required',
        'content' => 'required',
    ]);
```

Here is my validation. Tablename is **Leaves**. employee, bemployee and ldate are fields in table.

How can i check **employee** exists as **bemployee** in where **ldate= $ldate**?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: exists:bemployee,bemployee =>> bemployee is table or column or both?

Comment: i have edited. leaves is table, bemployee is fieldname

Answer (score 0):

```
$valid= Validator::make($request, [
        'contact'=> ['required',Rule::exists('tableName')->where(function ($query) use ($request) {
                        $query->where('column',$request->yourField);}),
                    ],
    ],
);
if($valid->fails()){
    // code
}else{
    // code
}
```

Comment: There is no change from my code.   i need where condition in that

Comment: for this you need to create custom validation like above

Comment: and don't forget to add use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;